# How to return the column of data to the combo box in vb.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

This is the code in one form.

```
D_AUTHORS.DataSource = Authors_Module.show_all_the_authors()
```

This is the function form another form.

```
Public Function show_all_the_authors() As DataTable
....
....
Return dt
End Function
```

Here D_AUTHORS is a DataGridView. I just call the show_all_the_authors() method from Authors_Module to return the value to the DataGridView. I have used DataTable as return type.

In the same way, I want to return the value to the combo box.

```
  C_DISTRICT.DataSource = Combo_Loader_Module.load_district()
```

where C_DISTRICT is a combo box.

```
Public Function load_district() As DataTable
    DB_Con_Module.con.Open()
    Dim strsql As String = "SELECT DSNAME FROM DISTRICT ORDER BY DSNAME"
    Dim cmd_district As New MySqlCommand(strsql, DB_Con_Module.con)
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_district)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("DSNAME")
    da.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Return dt
    End If
    DB_Con_Module.con.Close()
End Function
```

So, I used the same return type here also but it fails.

```
Public Sub load_district()
    DB_Connections.con.Open()
    Dim strsql As String = "SELECT DSNAME FROM DISTRICT ORDER BY DSNAME"
    Dim cmd_district As New MySqlCommand(strsql, DB_Connections.con)
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd_district)
    Dim dt As New DataTable("district")
    da.Fill(dt) 
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Authors.C_DISTRICT.DataSource = dt
        Authors.C_DISTRICT.DisplayMember = "DSNAME"
    End If
    DB_Connections.con.Close()
End Sub
```

This function (i.e.) while without returning value it works. 
But when I trying to return the value as

```
Return dt
```

then It fails. Why it happened so? Where I did mistake?

[image: This is the output that I got]

Comment: Replace the `...` with the actual code for `Function load_district`.  You say it is the same as the sub version, but we need to see the code which fails.  Also *how* does it fail?  Is there an error message?  Several of those object should be disposed - your app is leaking

Comment: Yeah I provided the full code. That image is the output that I got. @ Plutonix

Comment: `C_DISTRICT.DisplayMember = "DSNAME"`  you didnt tell it which column in the datatable to show

Comment: DSNAME is the column name to be showed.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: What do you come to say by 'your app is leaking'? @ Plutonix